# Error in executing a string dynamically

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have a pl sql code with repeated execution of a package with different procedure.When I am compiling that,it compiles with warning,but no errors.Here is the code:

```
for v_col_name in (select col_table_name from tbl_name)
loop    
   v_execute_string := 'package.'||v_col_name (par1 ,par2);
   execute immediate 'begin '|| v_execute_string; 'end;'
end loop
```

**Error:**

> PROCEDURE abc compiled Warning: execution completed with warning

When checking for that,it shows as if the problem is in the below part:

```
execute immediate 'begin '|| v_execute_string; 'end;'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are missing the concatenation operator between the variable and the second hardcoded string.

Answer (score 2):

You've got a semicolon, which ends a line, in between v_execute_string and 'end;'.

Should be `execute immediate 'begin '|| v_execute_string || ' end;'`

And unless v_col_name is a procedure too... you should probably make the line before like:

```
v_execute_string := 'package.'||v_col_name||'(par1 ,par2)';
```